# Use RTF for Skype's mood text

Tags: c#, rtf, skype4com

I don't get any errors and the property actually changes my mood text (after allowing my app access to Skype), but it doesn't use RTF, it just sets my mood text to `{\i Test}` instead of *`Test`*. I already tried to create a [`FlowDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and convert its content to RTF, but this didn't work either.

```
using SKYPE4COMLib; // Reference to Skype4COM.dll
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Program {

    public static void Main () {
        Skype skype = new Skype();
        skype.CurrentUserProfile.RichMoodText = "{\\i Test}";
    }
}
```

Has someone an idea on how to make Skype use RTF for this mood text (without using this Rich Mood Editor plugin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why it doesn't work is that Skype will look for HTML tags instead of RTF tags. So that is your problem. The usable HTML tags in `Skype.CurrentUserProfile.RichMoodText` would be

- `<i>Italics</i>`
- `<b>Bold</b>`
- `<u>Underline</u>`
- `<font>Font tags</font>(which includes color and size)`
- `<center>Center</center>`
- `<blink>Blink</blink>`
- `<a href="http://example.org">Linking</a>`

This is a fixed version of your code.

```
using SKYPE4COMLib; // Reference to Skype4COM.dll
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Program {

    public static void Main () {
        Skype skype = new Skype();
        Skype.CurrentUserProfile.RichMoodText = "<i>Test</i>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know, why I didn't try this before... Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome. I think there are more HTML tags for use in Skype moods, I will have to check up on the subject.